# How to update the mapping information of an entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

I would like to change the [default mapping of the Product entity](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusProductBundle/blob/d60fc2c410681b1f914f10ac170b7c6351a6ddf5/Resources/config/doctrine/model/Product.orm.xml#L42) from the Sylius ProductBundle. So I created a listener to the `ClassMetadata` Event:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Symfony\EventListener\Sylius;

use Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Product;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

/**
 * Remove the reference of a Variant from its parent (Product) without delete it
 */
class ProductLoadMetadataSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'loadClassMetadata',
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        /** @var ClassMetadata $metadata */
        $metadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

        if (Product::class !== $metadata->name) {
            return;
        }

        // Property "variants" in "Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Product" was already declared, but it must be declared only once
        $metadata->mapOneToMany([
            'fieldName'    => 'variants',
            'targetEntity' => 'Sylius\Component\Product\Model\VariantInterface',
            'mappedBy'   => 'object',
            'orphanRemoval' => false
        ]);

        //$variantsMapping = $metadata->getAssociationMapping('variants');
        //$variantsMapping['orphanRemoval'] = false;
    }
}
```

My goal is to set the `orphanRemoval` option value to `false` for the `variants` field.

But I didn't find a method or something else to update the ClassMetadataInfo instance.

At the moment I have this error:

> Property "variants" in "Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Product" was
>   already declared, but it must be declared only once

It's logical because the `variants` field already exists.

EDIT:

I tried another thing but without success:

```
unset($metadata->associationMappings['variants']['orphanRemoval']);

// setAssociationOverride doesn't handle 'orphanRemoval' but it calls internally _validateAndCompleteOneToManyMapping
// which set orphanRemoval to false by default
$metadata->setAssociationOverride('variants', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

To set `orphanRemoval`, you can try the following snippet:

```
if (SomeClass::class === $metadata->getName()) {
    if (isset($metadata->associationMappings['itemShippingTrackings'])) {
        $metadata->associationMappings['itemShippingTrackings']['orphanRemoval'] = false;
    }
}
```